# How to recover a Unicode string by its ASCII string in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, python-unicode

I'd like to give an example before ask my question.

```
u_string = u'\xcb\xa5\xb5'
u_string
Out[79]: 'Ë¥µ'
asc_string = ascii(u_string)
asc_string
Out[81]: "'\\xcb\\xa5\\xb5'"
```

Here, I finally get a ascii string(asc_string) only containing ascii characters.

My question is,
If I only have the asc_string, how can I convert it to the original u_string(Unicode string)?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: If you aren't concerned about security you can just use eval().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case, the simplest fully correct approach is [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> origversion = u'\xcb\xa5\xb5'  # Leading u is unnecessary on Python 3
>>> asciiform = ascii(origversion)
>>> origversion == ast.literal_eval(asciiform)
True
```

This works because using `ascii` on a string adds quotes and escapes to make a string that contains a string literal that reproduces the original string (it's just `repr`, but sticking to ASCII-only characters in the `repr`); `ast.literal_eval` is intended to parse canonical `repr`s (ASCII encoded or not) of literals to produce the resulting object, in this case a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode it like this:

```
asc_string.encode().decode( 'unicode-escape' )  
# "'Ë¥µ'"
```

I don't know why, but the ascii added an extra set of quotes, you can remove those like this:

```
asc_string.encode().decode( 'unicode-escape' )[1:-1]
# 'Ë¥µ'
```

Comment: This is a good solution when the string isn't quoted, but as you've noticed, it has the annoyance of needing to strip the quotes when you're done when using `ascii` (because `ascii` is basically "`repr`, but in ASCII form, and `repr`s of `str`s are always quoted). You also need to explicitly pass an argument to `encode`, `'latin-1'` (`unicode-escape` assumes latin-1 encoded bytes; if your locale encoding differs, some of the data will be corrupted).